# Symfony / Constrains & Validators on forms (email constrain)

Tags: symfony, validation, constraints, formbuilder

It's possible to create a custom email constrain validator (like @domain.com) using the "Custom Validation Constraint" of Symfony (http://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/custom_constraint.html) but not using the constrain in the Entity class?

I'm have an multitenant site in symfony and differents formsTypes for each client. One client needs that only can sing up X emails domains. In this case, I can't use a constrain in entity class like this:

```
class MyEntity
{
    /**
     * @Assert\Email()
     * @CustomAssert\EmailDomain(domains = {"yahoo.com", "gmail.com"})
     */
    protected $email;
```

Any different idea?

Comment: what is the problem or the error !

Comment: have you tried something ? you just have to create a validator and use it directly on the form, not on the entity

Comment: @ t-n-y How can i do this? (create a validator and use it directly on the form)

Comment: https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/without_class.html#adding-validation

Answer (score 0):

Yes, [custom annotation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/custom_constraint.html) can work on any class, they will be used when you call the `$validator->validate($yourClassInstantiated)`

If you want dynamic data (like domains depending on your client), you can use doctrine inside your ConstraintValidator class.

Comment: Link only answers tend to be down voted.  Especially when the link is actually in the question as well as not being relevant to the question.